# Copy history of subdirectory to parent directory

Tags: git

I'm developping a WordPress theme, in which I added a git repository keeping track of all the development.
I realize now that in order to use git to deploy to the server, I need my git repository to be all the way up to the wordpress directory (even though I'm only really tracking changes in my theme's directory).

Now I've created a git repo at the top level. How can I "import" my theme's history so I can continue developping it while keeping all its history ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a repository at the top level, convert the root of your existing repository to a top-level directory, e.g. add all the Wordpress files to your current directory and move your theme files to a directory below.

For example, say that you have the directory `mytheme` with the files:

```
mytheme
  +-- .git/
  |
  +-- theme.css
  +-- theme.html
```

Now you would just add the Wordpress files to the `mytheme` directory, and create the subdirectories for the theme (if needed):

```
mytheme <-- you can rename this to whatever you like
  +-- .git/
  |
  +-- mywordpressfile1.html
  +-- mywordpressfile1.css
  +-- mywordpressfile2.md
  +-- mywordpressfile3.config
  +-- themes/
         +-- mytheme/ <-- your files
                +-- theme.css
                +-- theme.html
```

You can rename the base `mytheme` to whatever you like since Git doesn't know about it.

Comment: It works, thank you. Now I have problems ignoring all the other WP files and keeping track only of my theme's directory. But that's another story I guess.

Comment: Nevermind my last sentence, I'd made a mistake in my .gitignore file. It's working.